# How to style html tables? - fill cell / enlarge image on hover / color one section

Tags: html, css, hover, image-enlarge

I am working with some html tables inside of html tables and I am having trouble doing some specific styling. Here is my table:
[image]

> **Note:** The blue part is the hover.

The specific things I want to do are:

```
1. Make the image in each cell fill the entire cell (instead of having that much blue space)
2. Make the image enlarge when you hover on the image.
3. Make the right section (with the info and buy button) have a light grey background.
```

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uS6tG/)

(the fiddle made my output looked stretched and Im not sure why)

Comment: Why is this a table?  You're not expressing tabular data.

Comment: I believe it is a table --- the content is in a <table> tag. Did you view the fiddle?

Comment: My question is not "is it a table", but "why is it one at all".  Tables are for expressing tabular data, you're using it purely for presentational purposes (which is considered to be a misuse of the element).

Comment: Ah ok. What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . change the `padding` of the .table td

2 . Something with `img:hover`, maybe this:

```
img:hover {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

But there you have to leave the browser window to get the old size...

3 . `<td bgcolor=gray>`